# Preventing a side of a SplitPane from resizing in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, splitpane

I have a layout where I have a vertical split pane that divides two components. The component inside the right side of the splitpane I want to grow (it's an image), but the components on the left side of the split pane I want to remain in the exact same place with the divider in the exact same position when the window is enlarged.

I have attempted to wrap the left side AnchorPane in a Vbox and it seemed to work except when the window is resized all of the components in the left side get moved down. This also occurs when I wrap it in an HBox.

I can't think of the best way to fix this. I'm using scene builder and I'm still fairly new to Javafx. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of the AnchorPane?

Comment: @Math Yes, both are set to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE

Comment: Try setting MaxWidth and MaxHeight to a defined pixel value to ensure that it doesn't grow beyond that.

Answer (score 7):

Calling `setMinWidth` and `setMaxWidth` on the component that must not grow with **the same fixed value** will prevent the user to change the divider position.

So for example let's say that you want a max size of `100` for your left component, the code could be:

```
SplitPane pane = new SplitPane();

double leftComponentSize = 100.0;
VBox leftComponent = new VBox();
// Set the min and max width to a fixed size
leftComponent.setMinWidth(leftComponentSize);
leftComponent.setMaxWidth(leftComponentSize);
...
pane.getItems().addAll(leftComponent, rightComponent);
// Initialize the divider positions to allocate the expected size 
// to the left component according to the size of the window
pane.setDividerPositions(leftComponentSize / stage.getScene().getWidth());
```